# How to add custom item in android Theme declaration?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I'm having few custom themes in my styles.xml 
Now whenever the activity takes the theme, it uses the **colorPrimary**, **colorPrimaryDark** and **colorAccent** values. 
For my layout's background I'm using **?attr/colorAccent**, so it can pick the background color based on the selected theme. 
If I use any of the above values it works fine. But I want to define a custom item value for my background color.
I tried like this below but it didn't worked. any ideas to make it work ?

My custom theme with custom value:

```
<style name = "customTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#4285f4</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#2C75F2</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#E1FFC7</item>
    <item name="customBgColor">#d3d3d3</item>
</style>
```

And I want to use it in layout's style as

```
<style name="layoutStyle" >
    <item name="android:background">?attr/customBgColor</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Create a `attrs.xml` file shown in image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

   <!-- Other values-->
   <attr name="customBgColor" format="reference" />

</resources>
```

[image]

**customTheme 1**

```
<style name = "customTheme1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Other values-->
    <item name="customBgColor">#d3d3d3</item>
</style>
```

**customTheme 2**

```
<style name = "customTheme2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Other values-->
    <!-- Black Color in theme2-->
    <item name="customBgColor">#111111</item>
</style>
```

Setting Color to `TextView`  as example.

You can use it in similar way in any widget anywhere.

This `TextView` is used in below activity.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_rate_us_about"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Rate us on Play Store!"
    android:textColor="?attr/customBgColor"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
```

Want to set theme dynamically.

```
public class AboutUsActivity extends Activity {
    
    int theme = 1;
    // int theme = 2;  2nd theme.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        switch (theme) {
            default:
            case 1:
                this.setTheme(R.style.customTheme1);
                break;
            case 2:
                this.setTheme(R.style.customTheme2);
                break;

        }
        // you must call `setTheme()` before `setContentView()`
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

    }
```

For multiple activities you have set theme for each of them separately.

Comment: I missed to define attributes, after adding attrs.xml, it's working fine. Thanks @sohail.

Comment: Instead of putting colour codes inside the item. put that in color.xml and add that colour tag into item..