# Can't set a Service layout style with a custom item color

Tags: java, android, android-styles, android-attributes

I have two android themes for my app. I want to create a new custom color value reference using attrs.xml however it's makes the app keep crashing.

Although I've seen other answers saying it's working fine with them as this one:
[How to add custom item in android Theme declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39826401/how-to-add-custom-item-in-android-theme-declaration)

here is my style.xml

```
    <resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="newValue">@color/black</item>
</style>


    <style name="Dark.AppTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#000000</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="newValue">@color/white</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

attrs.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="newValue" format="reference|color" />
</resources>
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF9800</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

view

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?newValue">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.moaness.servicetest.mainService: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3453)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1712)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6701)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:249)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:783)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)

.
.
.

     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f030140 a=-1}
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:946)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:930)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4738)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:597)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:248)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:244)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:240)
```

what is wrong with this code ?

Comment: `Unable to create service` – Are you trying to inflate that layout in a `Service`?

Comment: Yes, it's working fine without the new attribute

Comment: `Service`s don't really have themes on them, which is why it can't resolve that attribute. You'll need to wrap it with a `ContextThemeWrapper`, and get your `LayoutInflater` from that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36924702.

Comment: try to use: `android:background="?attr/newValue"`

Comment: @MikeM. your are correct! Please post that as an answer and I should accept it.

Comment: I've edited the question title to include the word `service` to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root issue is this:

```
UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute...
```

Whenever you see that during a layout inflation, it means that some attribute referenced in the layout (or in some drawable, color, etc. therein) is not available in the theme on the `Context` that the `LayoutInflater` is using to instantiate `View`s. In this case, that `Context` is a `Service`, and `Service`s do not have themes attached to them, by default.

To remedy this, simply wrap the `Service` in a `ContextThemeWrapper`, with the appropriate `R.style` value for the desired theme, and obtain the `LayoutInflater` from that. For example:

```
ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(MyService.this, R.style.AppTheme);
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctw);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.service_layout, null);
```

---

Another possible option would be to manually set a theme on the `Service` yourself, which would preclude the need for the `ContextThemeWrapper`. For example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
}
```

You can then obtain they `LayoutInflater` directly from the `Service`; e.g.,

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MyService.this);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.service_layout, null);
```

This should work everywhere, in theory, but since a `Service` doesn't normally have a theme, or manage a UI, I'm not certain that it can be relied upon in every environment, considering custom `Service` subclasses, manufacturer and custom ROM modifications, etc.

Indeed, I would say that the `ContextThemeWrapper` is the more solid solution.

Comment: Thanks Mike it's working 100% perfect. May I ask about embedding a `RecyclerView` inside my service, as it seems to be also struggling to get the theme entries. Is there any workarounds?

Comment: Well, it should be basically the same thing. Make sure the `LayoutInflater` you're using in the `Adapter` was created with an appropriately themed `Context`; that is, a `ContextThemeWrapper` like we created here.